# root of the word Virt

Tags: etymology

Originally "virtual" comes from Latin virtus, which can be translated like "force", "ability", "fact".

Why nowadays in many languages word derived from "virtual" mean something exactly opposite - something that cannot be touched.

Comment: Это не относится только к Русскому языку. "Virtual" - он и в Африке "virtual".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole class of words, called **Antagonyms** (Auto-antonyms, Contranyms). By definition, words that are antonyms to themselves.

There's [a brief list](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/704/27) of such words in English; Wikipedia also has [a decent list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) of those.

As of *"virtual"*, [Etymonline article](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=virtual) says:

> The meaning "being something in essence or effect, though not actually or in fact" is from mid-15c., **probably via sense of "capable of producing a certain effect"** (early 15c.). Computer sense of "not physically existing but made to appear by software" is attested from 1959.

Comment: I suggest changing OED to Etymoline (or Online Etymology Dictionary) since most people associate OED with the Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: "Vitrual" had a meaning of "physically impossible" long before computers were invented. It was very actively used in a context of classical mechanics (see virtual work, virtual displacement and virtual force). It appears in textbooks as old as of 19th century, and most likely was coined even earlier.

Answer (score 4):

But it doesn't mean the opposite. A force cannot be touched, nor can an ability or a fact. A thing can; the Latin for "thing" is *res*, whence *real*.

Words like "virtual", "practical", or "effective" all mean "for all intents and purposes — but not in essence". They refer to something that, if you like, walks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, but *isn't* a duck. Which is why in spite of their denoting a positive property rather than a lack of one, they can still be contrasted with "real", "literal" and "tangible".